# PHP-JWT not decoding

Tags: php, firebase-authentication, jwt, json-web-token

I'm using android library 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0' to create the token, which is properly creating the JWT which I've checked. My problem is when I use the php firebase/php-jwt library to decode. both libraries set to HS256 and key "testing".  What am I doing wrong here?

```
String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
            .claim("devId", getDeviceId())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "testing")
            .compact();
    logger.i(compactJws);
```

logs as eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkZXZJZCI6Ijc4MGQ1YWRlMzMwNGVhZmEifQ.XIKxG1xZbuMD8FRIAJ735LNbhodAj1a7pMZ6o3IF0ig

https://jwt.io/

[image]

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
$jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkZXZJZCI6Ijc4MGQ1YWRlMzMwNGVhZmEifQ.XIKxG1xZbuMD8FRIAJ735LNbhodAj1a7pMZ6o3IF0ig";
$key = "testing";
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
print_r($decoded);
```

returns Uncaught exception 'Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException' with message 'Signature verification failed'

Comment: secret base64 encoded is checked in the screen shot

Comment: So why did you show one JWT and used the other in your code? Its signature looks invalid, so what is your actual problem?

Comment: I used the incorrect screen shot. Ive update my code

Comment: I've also tried $key = base64_encode("testing");

Answer (score 1):

The answer was I was missing the "typ":"JWT" header and having to decode the key

```
Map<String, Object> header = new HashMap<>();
    header.put("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE);
    .setHeader(header)
```

PHP SIDE

```
 $decoded_array = (array) JWT::decode($jwt, base64_decode($key), array('HS256'));
```